# Automate some entries in Django models passing the entry value from same model

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
import shortuuid

class website(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    uid = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length=40,default=str(shortuuid.uuid(name=url)))

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.url
```

In django admin panel the value of `uid` does not change when I enter a `URL`.I just want to enter the URL and then want to generate the `uid` using `shortuuid` function.I want to set `uid` as `editable=False` but before that I want to ensure that the function is woking properly.How to automate the `uid` value passing `url` as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not where you would do it. You can't write something at the class level that depends on an instance attribute of the class: it's simply not possible. And what's more, a default is allocated when the object is instantiated, but you want that to change after the user has changed the value of another attribute, so this isn't a default at all.

Instead you probably want to define this value on save. That's easy to do by simply overriding the `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.uid:
        self.uid = str(shortuuid.uuid(name=self.user))
    return super(website, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: With a little correction it works.The argument name of `shortuuid` should be a string so it should be `name=str(self.url)` instead.I tried without it, its not working!